# How do I stop so many .blend1 files from being created

Tags: saving

Every time I save my files, it creates a new .blend1 file. I only want one backup. I have the same versions set to 1, but it saves a file every single time for some reason. Thanks for the help.

[image: Memory & limits]

[image: blend files settings]

[image: many .blend1]

Comment: Well you're renaming the file every time, so it doesn't find a match when it renames the file and a new .blend1 is created rather than the matching file being deleted beforehand.

Comment: If you have some form of version control running, the automated backup is completely redundant.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to turn off the backups altogether, Set <kbd>Save Versions</kbd> to <kbd>0</kbd> under Preferences > <kbd>Save & Load</kbd> then <kbd>Save Preferences</kbd>.

[image]

...and having researched further there is a built-in Blender addon with a pie menu for automatic incremental backups!
Search <kbd>pie</kbd> in addons and enable <kbd>Interface:</kbd> <kbd>3D Viewport Pie Menus.</kbd>

[image]

Open the Settings section and scroll down to and check the <kbd>Save Open Pie: Hotkey 'Ctrl >S'</kbd> entry. (All the others can be unchecked if you wish.)

[image]

When you use <kbd>⎈ Ctrl S</kbd> to save you will now get a pie menu which will look like this if you've not saved the file before:

[image]

The <kbd>Incremental Save >(unsaved)</kbd> entry (1) is disabled and using <kbd>Save</kbd> (2) will bring up the normal file dialog. Save as (e.g:) test.blend.

If you now <kbd>⎈ Ctrl S</kbd> again,
you can click on Incremental backup and your file will be saved automatically with the filename incremented as 'test_00x.blend' and each time you save the name is incremented by 1.

[image]

Using that method there's no need for a .blend1 file.

Comment: is there a way for only one backup saved?

Comment: See my updated answer.